# How to open *.idf eye tracker data that was created wih "i view X" system from "SMI"

Tags: python, eye-tracking, iview

The "IDF Converter" program is lost, SMI website doesn't include the programs.

Any way to open the *.idf files or convert them into any other format readable by python or MATLAB?

Comment: Contact me privately.

Comment: also check out this project: https://github.com/dcnieho/SMIidfExtractor by Niehorster and Nyström

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the IDF format is proprietary and encrypted, it seems to be. And SMI Vision was acquired by Apple in 2016, that's why the website is almost down.
The utility you need, IDF Converter, is contained as part of an iTools bundle.

Method 1. Download from [file sharing](http://gofile.me/2ytna/XoY6VvkzX) service.
The link kindly provided by [Dr. Kenneth Holmqvist](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kenneth_Holmqvist), Lund University.

Method 2. Search FTP servers, e.g. [searchftps.net](http://searchftps.net). In order to use it, you have to disable AdBlock, then try searching "iTools_setup.exe", and use dedicated downloading software like FreeDownloadManager or GetRight.

Comment: These programs don't seem to work with data recorded with SMI eye tracking glasses. I guessing they are for another SMI product. I receive the error: "The IDF converter does not handle Eye Tracking Glasses data. Please use Raw Data Export from BeGaze instead"

Comment: @IanZurutuza that is correct; SMI ETG recordings can only be converted with BeGaze, e.g. version 3.2.28; if you have Glasses, that also means you have a license for BeGaze, otherwise request the one who has to convert them for you before analysis